# Подсчитать вероятности символов, встречающихся в текстовом файле. Отсортировать вероятности символов по убыванию

Tags: c++, c

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string str, text;
    int chars[256] = {0}, i = 0;
    ifstream fin("test1.txt");
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(fin, str))
        {
            text += str;
            text += ' ';
        }
    }
    int s = text.length();
    text.erase(s-1,1);
    cout << text << endl;
    s--;
    for(int i=0; text[i]; i++)
        chars[text[i]]++;
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if(chars[i])
            cout << "Symbol probability '" << char(i) << "is" << float(chars[i])/s*100 << "%" << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять как отсортировать вероятности по убыванию, пытался отсортировать при помощи sort в результате получал отсортированные вероятности, но буквы были не те которые находились в файле.
Пример с sort:
Symbol probability ы is 3
Не понятно откуда взялась русская буква ы. В файле были латинские буквы.

Comment: Не разбираюсь в C++ с его итераторами. Но да, конечно не будет. Занеси все в map<char, int>, где в качестве ключа выступает конкретный символ, а в качестве значения - число элементов. Потом просто увеличивай map[sym] на 1. В конце программы для нахождения вероятности раздели каждое значение мапа на число символов в файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сортировка работает, но выводит странные ответы, потому что индексы являются и кодами символов. А после сортировки эта привязка теряется... и видим странное-странное.

Перепишем

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream fin("test1.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    std::map<char, int> m;
    char c;
    int counter = 0;
    // читаем по символу и сразу в мапу
    // ключ мапы - символы
    while (fin.get(c))
    {
        m[c]++;
        counter++;
    }
    using record = std::pair<char, int>;
    // мапа уже отсортирована, но не так, как нам нужно
    // перепишем в вектор
    std::vector<record> sm{m.begin(), m.end()};
    std::sort(sm.begin(), sm.end(), [](const record& a, const record& b) {return a.second > b.second;});
    // и выводим так, как Вы хотели
    for(const record& ch : sm)
    {
        cout << "Symbol probability '" << ch.first << "' is " << float(ch.second)/counter*100 << "%" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

в выводе будет одна странность, но думаю, одним маленьким if Вы ее поборите.